# Find sorting of two lists to match sum

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

This is a riddle on coding. I'm not sure if this is a good question but I struggle finding a solution.
I have two tuples `A = (9,2,58,58)` and `B = (57,1,57,8)`.
**Is there a way to sort list B so that B-A gives all the same result?**
The answer would be `Bs = (8,1,57,57)` with `B-A = (-1,-1,-1,-1)`
**But how can I find this sorting algorithmically?**

Comment: Is the order guaranteed to exist?

Comment: Those are tuples not lists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could approach this along these lines:

```
A = (9,2,58,58)
B = (57,1,57,8)

diff = (sum(B) - sum(A)) // len(A)

B_sorted = tuple(x + diff for x in A)
# (8, 1, 57, 57)

# assert sorted(B) == sorted(B_sorted)
# if the assertion fails, no such ordering exists
```

The logic: If you can get from `A` to `B` by adding the same number `diff` to each element, it must hold that

```
sum(A) + len(A) * diff = sum(B)
```

Then you use this formula to calculate `diff` and apply the addition.

Comment: The solution is quite good (+1), but cannot get the hang of the algorithm. Can you explain it

Comment: @Sujay Added some explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @blhsing THis is in line with my (unanswered) question, whether such an ordering of `B` is guaranteed to exist. We will always generate a `B_sorted` of integers, but whether that is actually a permutation of `B` is not sure because of the information we lose in the floor division.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. I started fiddling with permutations but your code is much shorter (and I guess faster).

Comment: Defintiely faster for longer tuples. Permutations grow exponentially with tuple length, while this approach has linear complexity (the sanity-check sorting is loglinear, but that could be done in linear time as well with a `Counter` comparison; loglinear is still miles better than exponential).